# Supervisord keeps restarting process regardless of autorestart being equal to false

Tags: supervisord

I am working on having supervisord send a curl request upon start. however, despite my best efforts, I set auto restart to false, it keeps running the script.

```
[program:slack-client]
priority=99
autorestart=false
command=bash -c 'SOME BASH COMMAND'
```

The error that keeps repeating is

```
INFO exited: slack-client (exit status 0; not expected)
```

Comment: Have you ran supervisorctl update/reread after the config change? Have a look here:
http://www.onurguzel.com/supervisord-restarting-and-reloading/

Also, I suggest you create/debug your script and have something like:
command=/path/to/bash_script.sh
This should work.

Comment: Actually what ended up fixing it was changing my supervisor.conf file, and append a exitstatus=0 to the end. 

nw everything works.

Comment: Can you please add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

`exitstatus=0` should be the default as per the current version in 2023. You might want to set `startsecs=0` such that even if the return code is acceptable, it does not get treated as FAILURE.

Answer (score -1):

Changing my `supervisor.conf` file, and append a

`exitstatus=0`